# Manjaro not booting and getting “[FAILED] Failed to start…” errors

Tags: linux, boot, manjaro

I'm having trouble getting into Manjaro.

I get into the "Welcome to Manjaro" screen where I can select language and keyboard and so on. But when I want to run Manjaro I get the following stuff on my screen.

I've tried it with both Etcher and Rufus, same errors. What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to [check if your download has the right checksum](https://wiki.manjaro.org/index.php?title=Check_a_Downloaded_ISO_Image_For_Errors)? (A quick way to make sure you downloaded the file with no errors)

Otherwise, try to work with your boot options, notably any compatibility setting (legacy, uefi etc..), fast boot or not...

Welcome to Super User btw :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are on ryzen 3th gen maybe update your bios.

I had Asus prime x570-p on bios 0807 and Ryzen 5 3600. I updated it to bios 1005. And now Manjaro starts normally.